# Знаете ли вы сайты где есть готовые части сайтов написание написанные на React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть такой сайт как w3.school, там есть готовые части сайтов на чистом javascript, такие как слайдер, модальные изображения,всплывающие формы, кнопки которые что-то открывают и многое другое. Знаете ли вы схожие сайты где есть готовые части сайтов написанные на React?
Пока нашел только https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/simp...
Но там только готовые слайдеры.

Comment: Выбираете любой UI Kit и получаете набор компонентов, например https://react.semantic-ui.com/
Так же полезная ссылка: https://ru.reactjs.org/community/ui-components.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ссылка которую вы указали это сайт **React Slick** это React версия слайдера Slick.

А то что вы хотите (и все другое) это есть на сайте [**React.rocks**](https://react.rocks/)